# Interaction VS and other program

Tags: c#

I've written a DLL that parses XML and returns Dictionary with tag name and its value. I'm using it in other program called ZennoPoster Project Maker. Here's the code:

```
XMLWork.XMLWorker worker = new XMLWork.XMLWorker(); // My parse class
string path = @"Z:\New\test.xml";
Dictionary<string, string> data = worker.GetData(path); // GetData - method, that returns
                                                        // data from XML
project.Variables["second_name"].Value = data["second_name"];
```

This block of code I must remake into XMLWorker class method and return a `project` type and in ZennoPoster I have to with 1 line of code return data. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the following simplified types:

```
namespace Objects
{
    public class Project
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Variable> Variables { get; set; }
    }
    public  class Variable
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You could structure your `XMLWorker` class like this:

```
using Objects;

public class XMLWorker
{
    public Project Project { get; private set; }
    public XMLWorker(string path)
    {
        Project = new Project();
        Dictionary<string, string> data = GetData(path);
        Project.Variables["second_name"].Value = data["second_name"];
    }

    internal Dictionary<string, string> GetData(string path)
    {
        // method implementation
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var project = (new XMLWork.XMLWorker(@"Z:\New\test.xml")).Project;
```